# Which tag should I choose between the most specific one and the most general one?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example, my question is about submitting a form: should I use the [submit](/questions/tagged/submit) tag (x 2061) or the [form-submit](/questions/tagged/form-submit) one (x 891)?

This example is not really expressive, but sometimes, there are much more people following the more general one than the more specific one, so it could be a better choice, even if the more specific one is more meaningful.

Comment: in this case, I think [tag:form-submit] should be synonymed to [tag:submit]

Comment: @WouterJ I'd be hesitant to do that. I think that it should be the other way around - form-submit tells me much more about what it exactly is before I read the wiki - submit could be applied to practically anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, of what use are specific tags at all, if they are not used when they apply? So from that, I'd say use the specific one <sub>(even if I can imagine situations where it would make sense to use them in tandem, saying it's both about the general case and the specific subcase).</sub>